Exercise 1.43. in the book Lectures on Euclidean Geometry 1 by Paris Pamfilos
I am studying geometry self-taught from the book Lectures on Euclidian Geometry by Paris Pamfilos, but I think I have apparently found an error. The exercise is the following:

Exercise 1.43. Extend the sides ${AB, A\Gamma}$ of the triangle $AB\Gamma$, whose angle $\hat{B}$ is acute, to their double ${AB^{'}, A\Gamma^{'}}$. Show that $|B\Gamma|<|\Gamma B^{'}|<|B^{'}\Gamma^{'}|$ 

According to my understanding, conditions are necessary to prevent that $|\Gamma B^{'}|>|B^{'}\Gamma^{'}|$
The representation of the triangle is my particular selection to represent said triangle, but the only conditions that it is asked to meet are those described in the exercise.

You're right. I would take the exercise at face value with the configuration shown and, add, say, that $\angle{B} > \angle{\Gamma}$, both acute, to avoid the case you're mentioning.

There is the case in which both angles are acute and depending on the height of the triangle it can be shown $|\Gamma B^{'}|>|B^{'}\Gamma^{'}|$.

Ha you're right. Well, at this point you're getting more out of the exercise than was intended =). Perhaps the right problem statement for you is: under what conditions does the inequality hold.
